# Bevel acting weird for corner

Tags: bevel

[image]

I've got this block here that I'm trying to turn into a pavement corner adjacent to a road. Imagine the road is on the outside of the corner and buildings are on the inside. All I'm trying to do currently is round the edge to make it a smooth corner, but for some reason the bevel modifier is giving me strange results.

For example, when I select the corner edge shown in the picture and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, it does this;

[image]

It's way more over one side than the other?

Is anyone able to help or advise me on this?

(If it helps, the right hand extension used to be longer, but I brought it back to the exact same length because of my problem)

Comment: have you tried applying scale? in object mode press `Ctrl`+`A` then select *Apply Scale*

Comment: If the scale is applied though (but it doesn't look like it, so I guess Harry is right), then maybe you have set the bevel option _Width Type_ to something different then "Offset". For example, "Percent" would create uneven bevel offsets if the extensions are different in size. That's just to show there can be different reasons depending on the mesh and the settings. But as I said, I guess it's the scale, too.

Comment: I would not use n-gons when beveling. Internally Blender converts them and depending on where it chooses to divide them (invisibly) discrepancies like this occur.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Sorry, that's simply not true. The beveling works completely fine with n-gons like these. As long as there is no scaling issue and no overlapping by e.g. too dense geometry, then beveling works as expected, especially with very simple edges like these 90° angles.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yeah that fixed it, thanks dude!